# The event 'onchange' I added to my checkbox doesn't work in JavaScript

Tags: html, dom, event-handling, dom-events

I'm working on creating a basic ToDo list on web includes adding tasks:
represented in  structure -
and deleting tasks, once the task is 'checked

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TheToDoList</title>
</head>

<script>
let counter = 0
let tasks = []

function removeTask(){
    console.log(counter)
}

function addTask(){
    var task = document.getElementById("tsk").value;
    var div = document.getElementById("tsklst");
    var input = document.createElement("input")
    input.type = "checkbox";
    input.id = counter;
    input.value = task;
    input.onchange = removeTask;
    var lable = document.createElement("lable");
    lable.innerText = task;
    lable.for = counter;
    div.appendChild(input);
    div.appendChild(lable);
    div.innerHTML += '</br>'
    tasks.push(document.getElementById(counter))
    counter++;
}
</script>

<body>
<h1>My ToDo List</h1>
<input id="tsk" type="text" placeholder="What You Need To Do?">
<input type="button" value="Add Task" onclick="addTask()">
<div id="tsklst"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

once a user click on "add task" button the addTask function creates the checkbox with lable contains to task that was written.

the problem is that although i define the onchange event of every checkbox i create,  when i check it through the browser - the removeTask function does not respond for some reason.

i put a console.log within the removeTask function, with a counter of the tasks to exemine the situation. - still can't figure it out what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment your code and set the change event using setAttribute

```
// input.onchange = 'removeTask()';
input.setAttribute('onChange', 'removeTask()');
```

Hope this will work for you. You can inspect that the event attached to your checkbox element

Answer (score 2):

When you use `innerHTML` the HTML is kept but the reference to the events is lost. You should use another way to add that `<br>` like `createElement`/`appendChild`.

```
// div.innerHTML += '</br>'
var br = document.createElement("br")
div.appendChild(br);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code does not work with this line:

```
 input.onchange = removeTask;
```

You need to change it to this:

```
 input.setAttribute('onChange', removeTask());
```

The other answer looks correct, but that version of the code did not work for me in JSFiddle. This one does work, I am sure it will fix the issue for you.

Code test in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tb68ay9z/1/